# Update to the imported file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I am trying to import a class which I have written in Python. Let's call it XYZ. I am trying to use this in a python script.

I import this in my script.py using:

```
from XYZ import XYZ
xyz = XYZ()
xyz.a()
xyz.b()
```

Now, If I try to update my XYZ class, its not reflected when I run script.py.
Is there a way to clear cache so that it looks at the latest XYZ everytime I run script.py?
I tried doing:

```
reload(XYZ)
```

But that fails with:

> TypeError: reload() argument must be a module

Comment: Yes, everytime you run `script.py` it will start with the `import` statement and read your `XYZ `module.

Comment: delete the .pyc file?

Comment: if the module XYZ installed with pip ? or does it directly uses the sources ?

Comment: You could try: `from XYZ import XYZ as Xyz; xyz = Xyz(); ... reload(XYZ)`

Comment: @azro: XYZ is not exactly a module, its something I have written locally.

Comment: @ChristopherHoffman: I do not see a *.pyc created for script.py Is it only created at the end of execution? My script.py is hanging because of a bug in XYZ module which I am trying to fix, But script.py never sees the updated XYZ

Comment: @Rgarg There should be an XYZ.pyc module file somewhere depending how you are developing.  Eclipse creates subdirectories and packages, so i moved to one directoy and put all the .py's in there and invoke with `python module.py`.  If your module has a main its `python -m Module`  this will generate an .pyc file in the same directory you invoke python.  .pyc is what is actually getting executed after its run through the python interpreter.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the path from which the module is getting imported? Removing pyc did not help. I am inserting a bug in XYZ and yet, the script.py does not fail/error out. I am wondering if there might be a name conflict

Comment: Rgarg: Any python script you `import` is a "module".

Answer (score 0):

The imported module is recompiled each time you run script.py and reflect your changes. `reload` is only required if you are running interactively. If all fails try deleting the __pycache__ directory (or *.pyc files if using python 2).